# Verb "escape": with or without preposition?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

I have already seen the verb "escape" with preposition ("from") and without. Is one of the uses the correct?

Comment: There is a rule that allows skipping the preposition, but right now it escapes me.

Comment: (According to [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/escape) the word can be either transitive or intransitive.)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you look up "escape" in a dictionary such as Oald which gives a survey about the possible verb constructions.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/escape_1?q=escape

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the context.

"Our prisoner has escaped" is perfectly fine.

"I have escaped from Alcatraz" is, too.

Comment: Someone downvoted your answer, so I upvoted it. It does answer this rather open-ended question. I'm not sure who is going around downvoting legitimate answers...

Comment: @TimWard I think the Original Poster is asking about a transitive verb usage of to *escape something* and a phrasal verb usage of to *escape from something*. This post doesn't answer the question and has no research or link to back up the answer. Furthermore, the question is general reference which is easily answerable by looking up the dictionary. Upvoting an answer just because some users downvoted it doesn't help the community.

Comment: Hi, Zbynek, please try to include research or link to support your answer in accordance with the guidelines of our Help Center.

Comment: I wasn't aware you need "research" or "links" to know how trivial English phraseology works.

Comment: @Rathony, I didn't upvote it just because it was downvoted. Read my second sentence, please. :)

Comment: @Rathony, furthermore, I thought the guideline was that if you're going to downvote, you should leave a comment explaining why it was downvoted. That seems a reasonable expectation, but I don't see that happening often.

Comment: @ZbyněkDráb You are right. It might not be necessary. The thing is the question is off-topic as it is general reference. It is not encouraged to answer this kind of question here. You will learn more as time goes by. But please see if a question is too basic. We have English Language Learners where this kind of question belongs, but I doubt it would be on-topic there.

Comment: @TimWard There is no such guideline here. Please read the [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). It is OK to downvote a post without leaving any comment even though you feel it is not the right thing to do. As I commented above to Zbynek, the question is off-topic. We should not encourage answering off-topic questions.

Comment: @Rathony, if you downvote, there is a pop-up that states: "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved." I consider that a guideline. What would you call it? This is a rhetorical question. You don't need to answer me. Just wanted to point that out.

Comment: @TimWard That's a suggestion. You don't see it after you have more than 2,000 reputation points. If you visit Meta Stack Exchange, you will see a lot of [discussions on this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=downvote+without+comment). Basic guideline is it is better to leave a comment, but it is not **absolutely necessary**.

Comment: In other words, I was downvoted for being helpful where I apparently should have dismissed the question and directed OP to ELL.